# When To Use Command / Event / Repository Patterns in MVC Pattern Applications / Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, events, model-view-controller, command-pattern

I'm having a little problem understanding the whole Command ( now Job ) | Event | Repository Coding Patterns in MVC applications, specially in Laravel.
I understand the basic of each one, What i don't understand is when to know and be sure that we should use each one.
I know there is no way to be sure which one of these patterns our task handling falls into, and it depends a lot on developer's pers*emphasized text*onal preference, But i would appreciate if someone can clear these concepts for me a little more.

> Say we want to save a book to our application, What i would normally do is create the Route > Controller > Repository > Model and divide the job between them in a way it most makes sense.
>   In this model, we can use Eventing in a way like firing an event when we're done saving the item (Book) and listen for it somewhere else in the program so we can add it to the notification table of our database which will alert the admin/user/...

Now, i'm not sure if this is "A" correct way of handling such matter, but, what i am mostly curious to know, is this:

**"Should i use a Command for saving the item or i can just pass the information straight from the Controller to the Repository and save it there?
Which way agrees to the patterns the most?**

**And lastly, Can you give some examples of using commands in such applications?**

Thanks in advance,
I appreciate both your time and patience.

Answer (score 1):

Commands are used to execute tasks from the command line - this might be useful from a cron job or from tools as supervisor for example. I often use them for admin tasks I don't want to provide an user interface for (at that point of time). REal life example: a command used in a cron job to import data from 3rd party software like SAP/SAS.

Events: event driven programming is another way to decouple parts of the application. One part of the application fires an event and another part listens to it an executes something. You might find this very elegant or more difficult to debug. If you are still struggling with the basic concepts of an MVC framework I recommend to skip this approach for the moment.

As for "dividing code between controller, repository and model" it depends on your personal taste and maybe the size of the application. For a small sized application I would simply save the book in the controller. 10 Minutes. Done. For a larger application I would create a service class and call this service class from the controller. The service class uses the repository class which uses the model so the controller is very small and does not contain much "valuable code". I like to follow this article:

http://dfg.gd/blog/decoupling-your-code-in-laravel-using-repositiories-and-services

But I know many devs who do not follow this approach. ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much, but i'm not sure about what you said about the commands, sure that's one way ( or maybe even the most reasonable way ) to use them, but i've seen tutorials / Source codes where a professional developer use them for every part of an application that it feels like giving commands, and of course mostly places that it makes it more clean and not overcomplicated and unreadable.
Such a place would be when saving something in the database when it feels like commanding. To follow the example above, when we want to command our app to add notifications. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you have a link for such a source code? I have never seen something like this before so it might be interesting to see it. And (probably stupid question): you are not referring to the command design pattern but to "Laravel commands"?

Comment: I can`t remember the other places I saw examples of that but here is one :
https://laracasts.com/series/build-a-laravel-app-from-scratch/episodes/10

Comment: This is a video on Laracasts where Jeffrey Way ( My FAVORITE Developer and Teacher which I've learned so much from ) creates a command mainly to save a user to the database.
I realize this might be only an example but I hardly think one would give an example on usability of commands on something that never happens.
In answer to your other question, I thought Laravel uses the basic command pattern, maybe a little different and Laravely! but nonetheless basically the same deal.
Be happy to know your idea around this matter too.

Comment: @herrjeh42 interesting points but note that the author of the linked article has (more) [recently said](http://dfg.gd/blog/decoupling-your-code-in-laravel-using-repositiories-and-services#comment-2643517917): `I agree this is overkill (though this opinion has formed since writing this post). I think this approach would be a lot better without repositories, but still feel there is a good case for use of services especially in larger code bases.`